# Can we please undelete this question about Uncharted 4?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

The question ...

[How do the pirate tests in Uncharted 4 get reset?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145335/how-do-the-pirate-tests-in-uncharted-4-get-reset)

... was deleted by the OP, presumably in response to some (unwarranted) criticism about the question being off-topic.

I've now got an answer for it. Can we please, as a community, get this question undeleted.

Comment: After the meta discussion re:the on-topicness of of U4, and finding out the the first 3 games were definitely SciFi in ways, I believed U4 is on-topic because of our test ["**If it's set in an on-topic universe, it's on-topic**"](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/344/31178) and voted to undelete, which happened to be the final vote needed (unless it gets axed again)

Answer (score 2):

The question is not closed, but deleted by the querent. There's a significant difference between "closed" and "deleted," and it's *very* unusual for the Stack to un-delete something which was deleted by the original poster.

That said, if it were just closed I'd be casting a re-open vote because it's on topic, not because somebody has an answer for it. "Answerability" is not a topicality criterion as support for non-answerability is, in itself, fodder for an excellent answer in the Stack style.

Comment: My concern is that he deleted it because a few users decided to vocally berate him about it being off-topic, despite it being on-topic.

Comment: I fixed Valorum's post, changing "closed" to "deleted". Also, I don't think it's *that* unusual for OP-deleted posts to be undeleted if they're useful and interesting - here's a [couple](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/109411/revisions) of [examples](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/104493/revisions) off the top of my head.

Comment: When the post is valuable indeed (speak: has a positive score) then it is not really unusual to undelete it if it was just deleted for personal preference and not for actual serious reasons. You don't really have a right to delete valuable content. I do agree though, that answerability in itself is not a sufficient criterion for reopening something that's actually inappropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the question, it appears to be on topic with regard to being about the story of a video game, rather than the mechanics.

However, there's a concern brought up in the comments that the video game itself might not be SFF.

Before asking users with rep high enough to undelete (I'm not one!) could we have proof that it's an on topic game series? Otherwise, we could just see it being closed afterwards, or otherwise contested. There's many more users with VTC privileges, after all.

If it's truly on on topic work, then there's no reason to leave it deleted. And, we shouldn't have to worry about closure, either.

Comment: *Before asking users with rep high enough to undelete (I'm not one!)* - yes you are. 10k rep is [enough to cast undelete votes on questions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: [Is Uncharted 4 on topic for SFF:SE?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10366/is-uncharted-4-on-topic-for-sffse)

Comment: @Rand Mixing it up with the 20K version, I guess! Oops